# Gas and "Gas Used By Transaction" and how to get both values through json-rpc

Tags: transactions, blockchain, gas, json-rpc, fees

On testnet I am analyzing the following transaction https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x7b111a37998b25116b1a6962d393253bf09613dd083b420ec24ffc9a28bc74b6
having this attributes:

> Gas:  90000 and  Gas Used By Transaction: 21000

I guess 21000 is the actual fee applied to this tx, but what is Gas:    90000 then?

I am a bit confused because when querying this tx through json-rpc on my geth node using eth_getTransactionByHash method I got this result:

> gas => 0x15f90 = 90000

but there is no field gasUsed or similar. So it seems there is no way to find out actual tx fee, right?

**How can I get gasUsed value for a tx using json-rpc calls?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `gas` value is sent by the external account that created the transaction. With the transaction object `{ from: account: gas: 90000, ... }`. When you call `eth.getTransaction("0x..")` you get the same value.

The `gasUsed` can be retrieved with `eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x..")`.

Comment: Perfect, eth_getTransactionReceipt is just what I was looking for. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Gas: 900000 is the amount of gas you estimate the transaction will consume

Gas Used: 21000 is the actual gas consumed by the transaction